# Преобразовать str с байтами в bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Имею строку

```
s = "b'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00'"
```

Необходимо получить ее в байтах, т.е.:

```
b = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00'
type(b) = bytes
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Таки `"b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00'"` или `"b'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00'"`?

Comment: print(s) = "b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00'", значит s = "b'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00'"

Comment: следует найти место, которую эту строку породило и исправить его, чтобы выводились сами байты, а не их текстовое представление.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться волшебным модулем `ast`:

```
import ast

s = "b'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00'"
print(repr(s), type(s))

b = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(repr(b), type(b))
```

Консоль:

```
"b'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00'" <class 'str'>
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00' <class 'bytes'>
```